# How do you enchant and name items with /give using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you enchant and name items with /give using command blocks?

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your command

```
{display:{Name:"Test Name"},ench:[{id:19,lvl:1}]}
```

It  will give you a Item with the name "Test Name" with **knockback** 1.

You use this:

```
ench[{id:(enchantment_id,lvl:enchantment_level)}]
```

like that for enchantments. For names, use this:

```
display:{Name="Name of item"}
```

Remember to use curly brackets and colons inbetweeen.

If you just need the template for whatever reason, here it is pieced together:

```
/give @p (item id or minecraft:name) 1 0 {display:{Name:"(Name of item)"}, ench:[{id:(enchant id),lvl(1-sideways 8)},[{id:(enchant id),lvl(1-sideways 8)}, repeat enchant block...]}
```

Comment: Remember to use colons?

Comment: Enchantment 19 is Knockback, Sharpness is 16. Although I think `minecraft:sharpness` also works, if you don't want to remember numbers.

Comment: In the second text, there is no closing bracket for the `(`

Comment: I think you mean: `display:{Name:"Name of item"}`

Note the colon.

Comment: As of 1.13, `ench` is called `Enchantments` and `id`s are now strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 6):

To add on to 3dsboy08's answer, you can find a list that tells you which id corresponds to which enchantment [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment#Enchantments).  Also, in order to add multiple enchantments at once, you need to use the following syntax inside the "ench" part:

```
ench:[{id:0,lvl:4},{id:8,lvl:3}]
```

As a "full" example, the following command would give you a stick called "Irritating Stick" with Sharpness V *and* Knockback II:

```
/give excalibur223 stick 1 0 {display:{Name:"Irritating Stick"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:19,lvl:2}]}
```

If you are interested, you can find a table of other NBT tags you can add to items [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_Tags#Items).

Answer (score 5):

**Updated answer as of Java 1.16:**

```
/give @p minecraft:bow{display:Name:{'[{"text":"chuck mc norris"}]'}}
```

or

```
/give @p minecraft:bow{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"chuck mc norris\"}"}}
```

Mojang updated some of their JSON sequencing for the give command, and now the old name argument doesn't work like it used to. This is the updated command, giving you a bow whose name is "chuck mc norris".

Comment: In 1.14+, you can actually use single quoted strings instead of double quoted strings. So instead of: `Name:"{\"text\":\"This is ExpertCoder14's computer\"}"` try this instead: `Name:'[{"text":"This is ExpertCoder14\'s computer."}]'`

Comment: hmm, so strings don't work the same way in minecraft as in programming (i.e. java)? that's interesting. I had never noticed because I'm used to using double quotes.

Comment: Yes, they've changed it to be more like Python, accepting both single and double quoted strings. With all NBT JSON text string tags, they are now converted into single quoted `'` format, *no matter how you type them*. So typing `Name:"\"hello world\""` would **automatically** be converted into `Name:'"hello world"'`.

Comment: I don't really see why though, the answer would remain completely unchanged in that value is not added with the edit.

Comment: ah i see, i'll put that as the first option and the original as the second. i didn't realize that it replaces the backslashes, sorry. big brainfart.

Comment: The only problem is that with single quotes you now need to escape every **single quote** `\'` instead of every double quote. But this is still better, because you won't need to use single quotes anywhere in JSON text.

Answer (score 1):

The following command would give the nearest player a bow called `Chuck Norris' Gun` with the enchantments 48 (Power), 51 (Infinity), 50 (Flame) and 34 (Unbreaking). These enchantments are all level 10000.

```
/give @p bow 1 0 {display:{Name:"Chuck Norris' Gun"},ench:[{id:48,lvl:10000},{id:51,lvl:10000},{id:50,lvl:10000},{id:34,lvl:10000}]}
```

Comment: Edited the question to explain the command.

Answer (score 0):

This command would give the nearest player a book called `Death Note` with the enchantment 16 (Sharpness) level 100.

```
/give @p book 1 0 {display:{Name:"Death Note"},ench:[{id:16,lvl:100}]}
```

Comment: Edited the question to explain the command.