# How Do You Enchant, Name, and Give an Item Lore in Minecraft Using a Single Command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to do the commands already, but I can't seem to be able to get to do it all in one command, because I can't target an already made item so I can enchant, but not name/ give it lore.

Comment: What's the command you're using?

Comment: See [these](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144746/custom-names-and-lores-in-minecraft-1-7-2]) [two](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185451/how-do-you-enchant-and-name-items-with-give-using-command-blocks) posts and combine. For example: `/give WanderingPlayer leather_boots 1 0 {display:{Name:"My Boots",Lore:["These are my boots.","They're really cool."]},ench:[{id:8,lvl:3}]}`