# How do I add enchants along with name in command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/give @p minecraft:bow{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}}
```

Is what I am trying to add enchantments to but cannot seem to figure out how. {Sharp 5 Knockback 100}

I tried the following:

```
/give @p minecraft:lead{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1‌ 000},{display:{Name:‌ "{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}}
/give @p minecraft:bow{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}},{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000‌ }
/give @p minecraft:lead{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000}}
```

Java Edition: Vanilla, 1.16.4

Comment: What have you tried already? Please share your past trials that didn't work, or share research that you tried to look at but didn't help you.

Comment: /give @p minecraft:lead{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000},{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}} 



/give @p minecraft:bow{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}},{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000}

/give @p minecraft:lead{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000}}

Idk if its because I just woke up but yakno, Figured id ask.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185451/how-do-you-enchant-and-name-items-with-give-using-command-blocks

What i used to find the new 1.16 naming thing (From you)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349279/how-do-i-create-tools-with-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have malformed nbt.  In all the commands you’ve tried, you opened an array and never closed it.  What you’ve done.

```
Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000s}
```

What the correct way is.

```
Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000s}]
```

Notice in the bottom example there is a close bracket at the end and the top example there isn’t.  That is an example of malformed nbt.  Your final command is below.

```
/give @p minecraft:lead{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Test Name\"}"}, Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:1000s}]}
```

For later problems I suggest using mcstacker to generate commands.